# Why does this script print an extraneous 'none' in the output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written a simple script to help me better understand using classes. It generates a random character for a game. I defined the object and then call a function on that object that prints out the generated character. At the end of the printed block, there is an extraneous "None" that I'm not sure where it's coming from nor why it's being printed. Here's the sample output:

```
ted
Strength  : 20
Dexterity : 17
Hit Points: 100
Aura      : 100
Weapon    :  
Spell     :  
Item      :  
Element   :  
--------------------
None
```

In my code, the last line of `player.stats()` is `print "-" * 20` which is displayed right above "None". Here's the code that defines the object:

```
class Player(object):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.strength = randint(15, 20)
    self.dexterity = randint(15, 20)
    self.hit_points = 100
    self.aura = 100
    self.weapon = " "
    self.spell = " "
    self.item = " "
    self.element = " "

def stats(self):
    print "\n"
    print self.name
    print "Strength  : %d" % self.strength
    print "Dexterity : %d" % self.dexterity
    print "Hit Points: %d" % self.hit_points
    print "Aura      : %d" % self.aura
    print "Weapon    : %s" % self.weapon
    print "Spell      : %s" % self.spell
    print "Item      : %s" % self.item
    print "Element   : %s" % self.element
    print "-" * 20
```

The object is then instanced using this:

```
name = raw_input("Name your character: ")

player = Player(name)
print player.stats()
```

The complete code can be read [here at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3apb6M6t) if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print player.stats()
```

Is the culprit. `player.stats() == None`

You want just:

```
player.stats()
```

You'd do better to name your function `player.printStats()`.

---

Another option would be to make it return a string:

```
def stats(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        self.name
        "Strength  : %d" % self.strength,
        "Dexterity : %d" % self.dexterity,
        "Hit Points: %d" % self.hit_points,
        "Aura      : %d" % self.aura,
        "Weapon    : %s" % self.weapon,
        "Spell     : %s" % self.spell,
        "Item      : %s" % self.item,
        "Element   : %s" % self.element,
        "-" * 20
    ])
```

And then `print player.stats()` would behave as expected

Comment: Ahh, I see. That would be a better name for the function. I'm unfamiliar with `join` as that hasn't come up in the training yet. What benefit do I obtain in using that?

Comment: `join` is a more efficient way of joining a bunch of strings together.   Using a bunch of `+`s can lead to quadratic run time -- `join` won't do that.

Comment: @VinBreau: `glue.join([a, b, c])` is the same as `a + glue + b + glue + c`

Comment: Fantastic, that's really useful in the project I'm working on.

Comment: @SamMussmann That's not really the main issue. The big benefit of `join` is that of readability and clarity.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Maybe not in this context, but that's why it's better to accumulate a bunch of strings in a list and `join` them all at once rather than gradually accumulate them in a single string with `+`.

Answer (score 3):

The `stats()` method does not return anything. A function that doesn't return anything evaluates to `None`. Which is what you print.

So, don't print the return value of the function. Just call it. Now, you should rename the function as `printStats()` to make it clear what it does. And then just call it like this:

```
def printStats(self):
    ....

player = Player(name)
player.printStats()
```

Naming is a really important part of programming. A slightly poor choice of name often leads to confusion like this.

Comment: I see, because in calling that function, the printing is carried out by the function's definition. I would only need to `print` if I were printing a variable from within the object such as in `print player_stats.weapon` for example.

Comment: Yep, that's right. And that's exactly what you are doing in the body of your function.

Answer (score 2):

You print the return value of `player.stats()`:

```
print player.stats()
```

but the `.stats()` method does not have a return statement. The default return value of any function or method in python is `None`, if no return statement has been given:

```
>>> def foo():
...     pass
...
>>> print foo()
None
```

Either remove the `print` before the method call, or have `stats()` return a string to print instead of doing all the printing in the method.

Comment: That's enlightening and shows me the hole in my knowledge. Thanks.